# Creating a linked events in Google without using Recurrence Pattern

Tags: google-calendar-api, recurrence, recurring-events

We are trying to implement a middle-ware application to synchronize the Google(App G) events and Our application(App A) events. The problem we are facing is in creation of recurrent events from middle-ware application to Google. The App A does not use ICS format for recurring events. Instead, it uses a concept of parent-child relationship between events to denote linked events. But while trying to insert this data in Google, we end up creating an individual event for each child event as we don't have any recurrence pattern to set in event before inserting.

We have tried to look at any solution to link the events as recurrent AFTER inserting the events to Google. But could not find any solution. Is there anything we can do to show the inserted events as linked? It would work even if the events are marked as

```
RecurrenceException(com.google.gdata.model.gd.RecurrenceException).
```

Solutions and suggestions are welcome.